# Caught in loop and need to save files using command line to external harddrive

Tags: command-line, hard-drive, login, external-hdd

Last night I decided to update my Ubuntu 14.04. When the update finished I decided to reboot. When I did I got stuck in a login in loop. So, I came here to the board to look for answers. I found this link and tried some of the solutions to no avail. 
[Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop](https://askubuntu.com/questions/223501/ubuntu-gets-stuck-in-a-login-loop)

Before I go any further I would like to save my files via cli to an external harddrive. I have a Seagate FreeAgent external harddrive that I want to put my downloads, pictures, documents, etc. What are the command lines that I need to know in order to do this?

If anyone has a solution to the login loop problem I would love to hear it. This is pretty frustrating to see my files right there and not be able to access them.

Comment: What type of prompt do you have to work from?

Comment: Boot from live media and make a backup... you can avoid terminal that way

Comment: I use crtl, alt, f1 to get to the CLI. That is the prompt I am working from. I think that answers your question.

Comment: So, I can access my files using the live media disk? How does that work?

Comment: You boot the live disk and mount the hardisks. Does `startx` work from a TTY prompt (what desktop environment are you using)?

Comment: I am using the unity environment.

Answer (score 1):

From a command line prompt use the copy command. You need the path to your USB device.

Syntax

```
cp source destination
cp dir1 dir2
cp -option  source destination
cp -option1 -option2  source destination
```

From your question, you want

```
cp -r /home/username/Documents /usb_backup_destination
cp -r /home/username/Downloads /usb_backup_destination
```

and, so on for each directory you wish to copy.

If you need to find the path to your USB backup device, run

```
sudo blkid
```

The output for your device will be listed after all the HDD's an usually starts with **sdb**

```
/dev/sdb1: UUID="36C9-BC77" TYPE="vfat" PARTUUID="e10284e8-01"
```

with one line for each partition. The UUID, without quotes, will be needed to identify the target destination for your copy command. Your destination usually mounts as:

```
/media/<your_username/<your_sbd>
```

So, your copy command should look like this.

```
cp -r ~/Downloads /media/<your_username>/device_UUID
```

Answer (score 0):

`cp item directory` is how you copy files into a directory. If you want to copy a directory, make sure to use the `-r`    argument. Type in `man cp` for more info.

Comment: I don't understand. Could you please elaborate how to get the files to my external hd? Thanks for your response.

Comment: Say you wanted to copy a file called bob.txt to a directory called /exhdd. Go to the directory with the file called bob.txt and then in the shell prompt type in `cp bob.txt /exhdd`. Say bob.txt was in a directory called /bob and you wanted to copy the full directory to your external hdd . Then you would need to type in `cp -r /bob /exhdd`. Hope it is helpful.

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Will it work for a whole folder? Could I type "cp Documents /exhdd" ?

Comment: Let me try and clear it up more (I'm a bit new to linux as well). To find out the name of the directory of your exhdd, type in `cd /media`. This is the directory which usually contains mount points for removable media that are mounted automatically at insertion. Now make note of the name of the directory of your exhdd, I will refer to it as /exhdd in the shell command. In linux, folders are usually called directories. If Documents is the directory you want to copy, the command you need is `cd -r Documents /exhdd`. You need the `-r` recursive argument if you ever want to copy a directory.